# How do I click a button on cookies pop up using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi I want to click 'Save Services' using Selenium on this website to make the pop up disappear: https://www.hugoboss.com/uk/home. However I receive a timeout exception.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time 
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    from selenium import webdriver 
    import time
    
    
    driverfile = r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\Work\Projects\extra\chromedriver'
    
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverfile) 
    driver.get("https://www.hugoboss.com/uk/men/")
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'SAVE SERVICES')]"))).click()
```

Further information: When I try to find the x_path of the button using class: `//button[@data-testid='uc-save-button']` on the inspect element finder, It returns 0 results as if it does not exist?

I ran `len(driver.window_handles)` 10 seconds after the webpage was loaded and which returned 1, meaning selenium could see one window open only.

Comment: You didn't mention what exception you are receiving here... maybe add that to your post.  The button has a data-test-id attribute.  Use that for your xpath locator.  I would also check for stale element exceptions since the dom is updating somewhat frequently.  If using another .get() after this, be sure to add a sleep.  (chances are your choice there saves a cookie which needs to be waited for...)

Comment: Your button is in a shadow root - you'll need to handle it with JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element is in a shadow root. Find your element in devtools, scroll up and you'll see this in the DOM:

[image: shadowroot in devtools]

To get into the `shadowroot`, an easy way is the get it's parent item then use JS to get the object.

Within that returned object you can find your button:

edit:: Updated the code from the original answer. This runs for me:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

url = "https://www.hugoboss.com/uk/home"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
shadowRoot = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='usercentrics-root']").shadow_root
shadowRoot.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-save-button']").click()
```

#########

Update - a demo of the code working:
[image: gif]

`pip list` tells me I'm using:

```
selenium           4.1.3
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I get the error: 'InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: 'using' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)'

Comment: @user13174343  - Sorry about that.  I got the same error - I've run it this time - and the edit works

Comment: I still get this errorAttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'shadow_root'

Comment: @user13174343 Consider increasing the implicit wait time , adding and explit wait, debugging it or verifying your versions - I've upload a demo that the code provided works for me.  I've slowed it down with a couple of sleeps but please note that's not test synchronisation - it's just for the video.

Comment: @user13174343  - it's also worth saying in your question you say you want to hit `hugoboss.com/uk/home`  but in your code you used `hugoboss.com/uk/men/`   -  You can see all the code i've used and it works so perhaps verify the landing page is as expected?

Comment: I upgraded my selenium package, which worked! Thanks!